# Push notification ios from Firebase is received but no sound or in notification center

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification

I am able to receive notifications from firebase but sometimes the notification is received from 'did receive' function in the app. But there is no sound or alert in the Notification banner or in Notification center. It's critical alert which is having higher priority.

Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is open, the operating system will not present the banner or play a sound on its own. Instead, you get notified about the notification in your AppDelegate.

If you target iOS 10 or above, you can use `UNUserNotificationCenter` and it lets you present the notification even if your app is open. Below is an example:

In your `NUserNotificationCenterDelegate` object, pass `.alert`, `.badge` or `.sound` to the completion block of `willPresent notification` method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
     willPresent notification: UNNotification,
     withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Although be very cautious about this approach. Users can easily forbid your app from presenting any notifications. If so, the above method will result in nothing being shown to the user.

It may be a better approach to present all notifications yourself if your app is open.

Comment: Got it fixed. Thanks much